# PROCEDURE always return value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've just created a stored procedure like that:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GetSmth(IN f1 INT UNSIGNED, IN f2 VARCHAR(6))
BEGIN

   SELECT
      `ID`
   FROM
      `table`
   WHERE
         `f1`=f1
      AND
         `f2`=f2 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
      AND
         `f3` IS NULL
  ORDER BY `ID` DESC
  LIMIT 0, 1

END $$
```

Here's data in table:

```
ID | f1 |   f2   |  f3
 1 |  1 | 123456 | NULL
 2 |  1 | 555666 | 1
```

No matter what I call: `CALL GetSmth(3, '123456')`, `CALL GetSmth(1, '000000')` or whatever I still get `2` as a last `ID` in my table. Other stored procedures working just fine. I cannot figure out what's wrong with that one. When I call this `SELECT` statement without procedure, it's working. For example, if I pass `3` as `f1` value I won't get any results. But in procedure it will return `2`. My definer is ok (just like in other procedures) and `SQL Data Access` is set up as `CONTAINS SQL` - just like in other procedures.
Few words about table: InnoDB, `ID` - `INT UNSIGNED AI NOT NULL`, `f1` and `f2` are indexes `INDEX` (used as foreign key to another table). This table just like any other table.

Comment: Are you sure the procedure code is what you think it is? Try `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE GetSmth` and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally not a good idea to use parameter names that are identical to the field names in the queries they are to be used in. Try renaming the parameters to `p_f1` and `p_f2`.

Comment: I have nearly 20 other stored procedures where I have almost identical name like `UserFirstname` and `userFirstname` as a param. It's working great, no problemo.

Comment: @VladislavKasianenko Have you tried? This won't be the first time I've seen this problem. In those other stored procedures, are the field names perhaps being fully qualified in the queries?

Comment: I have hit this problem. I always just use leading underscore, eg `_f1`, so it visually stands out and never collides with a column name.

Comment: Well, yeah, actually it works. I have no idea why it's working on other procedures, but here it was not working. I changed my param names and it's working for now. Thank you.